# Rotating in Itextsharp while preserving comment location & orientation

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

To summarize, I'm using Itextsharp to import specific pages from a PDF, possibly rotate, resize or otherwise alter that page, and exporting it into a new PDF. To this end I'm using the PDFWriter class from Itext. The problem I'm running into is that when using the writer class, it doesn't appear to be including the visible annotations that appear on the source page (in my case it's a comment) in the output page. Interestingly it does include the embedded OCR without issue.

Additionally, when using the Itext PDFcopy class it does work just as I want it to (copying comments properly to source), unfortunately PDFcopy doesn't have a lot of easily accessible functionality for the sorts of things I need to do with the page (e.g. resizing pages).

So I am looking for one of two solutions:

-Preferably I'd like to continue to use the writer class, but need it to copy/duplicate any visible annotations etc. from the source pages and include them in the output.

-Need some example code of using the PDFCopy class to resize a page. There is a pdfcopy.Setpagesize function (which doesn't work, which I suspect means I'm doing it wrong), but I have basically no idea how to properly scale the source page when it needs to be resized.

Here's some pseudo code to give you an idea of where I'm at in terms of using the PDFWriter class:

```
      '...

Dim MS As New MemoryStream()
Dim document As New Document
Dim WriterPDF As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, MS)
Dim reader As PdfReader = Nothing
Dim cb As PdfContentByte = WriterPDF.DirectContent
reader = New PdfReader(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(FilePathList.Item(ItemNum))))

For Each PageItem As Integer In PageNumList
   Dim page As PdfImportedPage = WriterPDF.GetImportedPage(reader, PageItem)
   Dim PageSizeStandard As Rectangle = PageSize.LETTER
  document.SetPageSize(PageSizeStandard)

   Dim tm = New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix()

        'code to resize, rotate etc... tm.scale, tm.rotate, etc.

   cb.AddTemplate(page, tm)
   document.NewPage()

next
```

As the alternative, the PDFCopy code I'm using for rotation involves:

```
 Dim MasterCopy As PdfCopy = New PdfCopy(document, New FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
      '...
 Dim PageDict As PdfDictionary = reader.GetPageN(PageItem)
' can get current rotation with this... 
' Dim Rot As PdfNumber = PageDict.Get(PdfName.ROTATE)

      '...
Dim RotatedPageSizeHeight As Single = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(PageItem).Height
Dim RotatedPageSizeWidth As Single = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(PageItem).Width

If RotatedPageSizeWidth > RotatedPageSizeHeight Then
     PageDict.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, New PdfNumber(90))
     'there is a Pdfname.Size, but no idea if that's even what I need or how to use it.
     'with the writer class I use a matrix to scale the page, works fine. 
End If

      '... 
MasterCopy.AddPage(page)
```

Sorry the pseudo code is a bit fragmented, trying to keep it brief. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information. And thanks in advance!

Comment: You are ignoring the difference between page content (stored in a content stream, such as images, OCR'ed text,...) and annotations (stored in PDF dictionaries). As described in chapter 6 of my book ( http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf ), you are deliberately throwing away those annotations by using `PdfWriter`. If you only want to rotate pages in an existing PDF, the answer is really simple. If you also want to scale a PDF, you're in for a huge deal of programming work (and StackOverflow subscribers won't do your work in your place).

Comment: *If you also want to scale a PDF, you're in for a huge deal of programming work* - merely scaling could be achieved by means of the **UserUnit** page setting.

Comment: @Finch042 *or otherwise alter that page* - it's really difficult to take this into account in any answer...

Comment: I always assumed that **UserUnit** was an integer between 1 and 75000,  meaning you couldn't scale down. However, when checking ISO-32000-1, I found no confirmation for that assumption, so I'll need to double-check using an example (and probably write a correction for my book).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie **UserUnit** is a *positive number*, and its default value is **1.0** (the format indicates that non-integers are allowed)...

Comment: Admittedly there is a hint later on that it may not be less than 1... *Starting with PDF 1.6, the size of this unit may be specified as greater than 1 ⁄ 72 inch by means of the **UserUnit** entry of the page dictionary*; this does not explicitly *forbid* values less than 1, though.

Comment: I've sent the question to Adobe and to the person who is responsible for the Appendix regarding implementation limitations in ISO-32000-2. I can predict the answer: the ISO standard doesn't enforce limitations for the UserUnit, but it doesn't prohibit vendors to implement the UserUnit functionality in a way that certain limits are taken into account for its value. In practice this means that its value must be greater than or equal to 1 and lower than or equal to 75,000 (as that is how it's implemented by Adobe).

Comment: Adobe responded: "Correct that UserUnit can't be less than 1.0 and we should note that accordingly." In this context, "we" means the ISO committee for ISO-32000-2.

Comment: OK, good to know at least that that is likely to be added to the spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a small sample that implements what mkl suggests: [ScaleRotate](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/ScaleRotate).

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfDictionary page;
for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
    page = reader.getPageN(p);
    if (page.getAsNumber(PdfName.USERUNIT) == null)
        page.put(PdfName.USERUNIT, new PdfNumber(2.5f));
    page.remove(PdfName.ROTATE);
}
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Given an original PDF [pages.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/pages.pdf) with rotated pages, cropped pages and annotations. We scale and rotate some pages, resulting in [pages_altered.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/pages_altered.pdf).

We introduce a **UserUnit** of 2.5 for all pages that aren't scaled yet. If you change the **UserUnit** to 0.5, you'll see that it won't have any effect in Adobe Reader. The ISO standard for PDF says that the range that can be used for the user unit is implementation-independent. Version 1.7 of the PDF specification originally written by Adobe says: "Acrobat 7.0 supports a maximum UserUnit value of 75,000." Nothing is said about the minimum value, but experience tells us that the minimum value supported by Adobe Reader is 1, meaning you can't scale down.

As for the rotation, you can change the rotation of a page by changing the `/Rotate` key in the page dictionary. In the example, I removed the key, changing all pages shown in landscape (of which the value for `/Rotate` is 90) into portrait (the default value for `/Rotate` is 0). You'll notice that this doesn't have any effect on page 4. Page 4 isn't rotated. It looks like a page in landscape because the dimensions of the page are created in such a way that the width is greater than the height.

Summarized: it's a piece of cake to rotate pages in an existing PDF, so is scaling the pages up to a bigger size. If you want to downscale pages, you can only use `PdfWriter` (which throws away all annotations) and you need to copy the annotations separately *after* transforming all the `/Rect` values of these annotations. This is a huge task. It took one of our customers several weeks to achieve this correctly. Be prepared to spend an equal amount of time if that's what you want.

DISCLAIMER: the **UserUnit** value isn't supported by all viewers. Implementations may vary depending on the viewer that is used. The feature was introduced in PDF 1.6, meaning that the functionality won't work in any viewer supporting only older PDF versions.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, even if it wasn't all good news.