# Changing UserUnit of existing pdf with itext in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

i didn't found anything specific to that topic, therefore i'm using this board and hope to get a question/help.

What i have: i have a pdf-document, which is very big (adobe reader says: 21.399,4 x 15.123,7 mm, zoom-factory, when opened is ~1,64% screen-filling!). It's a construction drawing, but this doesn't matter. When i'm using sublime to analyze the structure, i can find the following:

- pdf-Version is: 1.6
- CropBox[0.0 0.0 14400.0 10177.0]
- /Rotate 0/Type/Page/UserUnit 4.2125

What i need: a smaller document, because of the big size, i can't go on with processing the file

What i tried: using iText to reduce the UserUnit to default "1" for the first step. This should make some things easier. My code in the java-programm looks like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile.getAbsolutePath());
try (FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outStream);
    PdfWriter writer = pdfStamper.getWriter();
    writer.setUserunit(1f);
    pdfStamper.close();
}
```

another thing, which i tried, was:

```
PdfDictionary pageDict;
pageDict = reader.getCatalog();
pageDict.put(PdfName.USERUNIT, new PdfNumber(1f));
```

Both things didn't work, so my questions are:

- Is it possible to change UserUnits of an existing file? Or do i need to create a new one with the properties i want to have and then writing the content of the existing pdf in my new one?
- if it's possible: what else do i need to do to change the UserUnits?

With greetings from Heidelberg,
sincerly
D. Pfizenmaier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ScaleRotate](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/ScaleRotate) example. It was written in answer to the question [Rotating in Itextsharp while preserving comment location & orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871027/rotating-in-itextsharp-while-preserving-comment-location-orientation) where you'll find more info about the user unit.

This is the code that is relevant:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfDictionary page;
for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
    page = reader.getPageN(p);
    page.put(PdfName.USERUNIT, new PdfNumber(1f));
}
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Note that you are getting the root of the document using `getCatalog()` but the name you give to the variable sounds as if you assume that it is a page dictionary. That won't work...

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Yes, I indeed thought that it's a page dictionary, but right, every single page in the document can have its own size and maybe UserUnits too. I thought UserUnit is globally set for the document. Now I know the difference, thanks.

Is my first approach incorrect, or why doesn't it work in this way?

Comment: The first approach uses a `PdfWriter` method that is meant for creating a document from scratch. Every new page you create will take the user unit you defined at the `PdfWriter` level. You are using it in the context of the internal `PdfWriter` instance of `PdfStamper`. That isn't supposed to work because you aren't creating any new pages; all pages already exist.