# iText7 scaling rotated document with links

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I am using iText7(java) and trying to scale a portrait document to landscape. The document contains links and has rotation set to 270. Setting mediabox and cropbox on document does not work due to rotation.
The solution mentioned in [iText Examples](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/4f3516fb0a21dbfa52f6fc123fdea8fc2d5c7691/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/events/ScaleDown.java) does not work properly and  hyperlinks in document stop working. There might be loss of other metadata as well .

Is there any way to scale the document without using copyAsFormXObject.
Following method in itext7 to manipulate documents works very well for adding footers, watermarks , etc. Is there any way to scale document in following code ?

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(srcDoc), new PdfWriter(outPut));
for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(i);
    page.setIgnorePageRotationForContent(true);
    // change page scaling here
}
pdfDoc.close();
```

I have following working code to copy links and scale document to full width. Anyone can use following code if that is all they need.

```
boolean isLandscape = CommonConstants.LAYOUT_LANDSCAPE.equalsIgnoreCase(vo.getLayout());

ByteArrayOutputStream resizedPdfBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(resizedPdfBytes);
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(mergedPdfBytes.toByteArray()));
        PdfDocument writerDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        PdfDocument readerDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
        Rectangle targetSize = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight());
        if(isLandscape){
             targetSize = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4.getHeight(), PageSize.A4.getWidth());
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= readerDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            PdfPage origPage = readerDoc.getPage(i);
            PdfPage page = writerDoc.addNewPage(new PageSize(targetSize));
            Rectangle orig = origPage.getPageSizeWithRotation();
            double heightScale = 1, widthScale = 1;
            widthScale = targetSize.getHeight() / orig.getHeight();
            heightScale = targetSize.getWidth() / orig.getWidth();              

            for (int k = 0; k < origPage.getAnnotsSize(); k++) {
                PdfAnnotation annotation = origPage.getAnnotations().get(k);
                PdfAnnotation annotation1 = new PdfLinkAnnotation(annotation.getPdfObject().copyTo(writerDoc));
                PdfArray array = new PdfArray();
                Rectangle oldArray = annotation.getRectangle().toRectangle();
                array.add(new PdfNumber(heightScale * oldArray.getLeft()));
                array.add(new PdfNumber(widthScale * oldArray.getTop()));
                array.add(new PdfNumber(heightScale * oldArray.getRight()));
                array.add(new PdfNumber(widthScale * oldArray.getBottom()));
                annotation1.setRectangle(array);
                page.addAnnotation(annotation1);
            }

            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

            AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(heightScale, widthScale);
            canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
            PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.copyAsFormXObject(writerDoc);
            canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, 0);
        }

        writerDoc.close();
        readerDoc.close();
```

This feels quite similar to itext2, I hope there is a better way to do this.

Comment: *scale a portrait document to landscape.* - what do you mean by that? You want scale it down with white areas left and right? Or do you want to rotate it?

Comment: I want reduce size and center on landscape view.